# Grouping with matches the previous element zero or one time doesn't capturing

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following url:

```
var = "/cars/bmw/x6/54d4190fcdc5900c78ef3bf6/postcode-rh69ta/100miles/min-1000/max-10000/under-10-years/under-100000-miles/automatic/hatchback/diesel";
```

each of the url parts optional and I want parse them with the following regex:

```
    var rxUrlParser = new Regex(
    @"(/postcode\-(?<postcode>\w+))?" +         //postcode
    @"(/(?<distance>\d+)miles)?" +              //distance
    @"(/min\-(?<minprice>\d+))?" +              //minprice
    @"(/max\-(?<maxprice>\d+))?" +              //maxprice
    @"(/(?<auo>under|over)-(?<age>\d+)-years)?" +            //age
    @"(/(?<muo>under|over)-(?<mileage>\d+)-miles)?" +        //mileage
    @"(/(?<trans>automatic|manual))?" +         //transmission
    @"(/(?<seller>trade|private))?" +           //seller
    @"(/(?<body>\b(HatchBack|Saloon|Estate|Coupe|Sports|Convertible|MPV|4[^A-Za-z0-9]*x[^A-Za-z0-9]*4|PickUp|Van)\b))?" +  //bodytype
    @"(/(?<fuel>\b(Petrol[^A-Za-z0-9]*Electric[^A-Za-z0-9]*Hybrid|Petrol[^A-Za-z0-9]*LPG[^A-Za-z0-9]*Hybrid|Diesel[^A-Za-z0-9]*Electric|Bioethanol|Petrol|Diesel|Electric|LPG)\b))?" +  //fuel
    @"(/(?<color>\b(Blue|Green|Brown|Red|Black|Beige|Pink|Yellow|Orange|White|Purple|Grey|Silver|Gold)\b))?" + //color
    @"(/(?<sort>price\-max|price\-min|distance|mileage|newest))?" //sort  
    , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

But the "Match" method of regex does not capturing any of them.

Comment: Are you sure? [Your code works fine on ideone](http://ideone.com/Aa8Y8w).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot full url. Full url was entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this behavior because all parts of your regex are optional. Therefore, it allows an empty match, which is what you get when you prefix the "payload" part of the URL with some other text.

If you "anchor" your regex to the end of the URL string by adding `$` at the end, it will work:

```
var rxUrlParser = new Regex(
    @"(/postcode\-(?<postcode>\w+))?" +         //postcode
    @"(/(?<distance>\d+)miles)?" +              //distance
    @"(/min\-(?<minprice>\d+))?" +              //minprice
    @"(/max\-(?<maxprice>\d+))?" +              //maxprice
    @"(/(?<auo>under|over)-(?<age>\d+)-years)?" +            //age
    @"(/(?<muo>under|over)-(?<mileage>\d+)-miles)?" +        //mileage
    @"(/(?<trans>automatic|manual))?" +         //transmission
    @"(/(?<seller>trade|private))?" +           //seller
    @"(/(?<body>\b(HatchBack|Saloon|Estate|Coupe|Sports|Convertible|MPV|4[^A-Za-z0-9]*x[^A-Za-z0-9]*4|PickUp|Van)\b))?" +  //bodytype
    @"(/(?<fuel>\b(Petrol[^A-Za-z0-9]*Electric[^A-Za-z0-9]*Hybrid|Petrol[^A-Za-z0-9]*LPG[^A-Za-z0-9]*Hybrid|Diesel[^A-Za-z0-9]*Electric|Bioethanol|Petrol|Diesel|Electric|LPG)\b))?" +  //fuel
    @"(/(?<color>\b(Blue|Green|Brown|Red|Black|Beige|Pink|Yellow|Orange|White|Purple|Grey|Silver|Gold)\b))?" + //color
    @"(/(?<sort>price\-max|price\-min|distance|mileage|newest))?$" //sort  
    //                          Here is the only change --------^
    , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/2YZtPX)